# Phpmyadmin doesn't show "privileges" tab

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, privileges

I have WAMP installed on Windows, and I can't seem to get the "privileges" tab to show in PhpMyAdmin no matter what. Reading other forum discussions and articles, I have done the following:

- Checked to make sure that I'm logged in as root
- Reinstalled wamp
- Reset my mysql users
- Run mysql check on users
- Cleared my cache

Through those tests, I have gotten the following error: `Can't find file: 'user' (errno: 2)`. A google search for a solution to that proved futile. Any help would be appreciated

**Update: Screenshot**
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Just to confirm, you do have a database selected, correct?

The privileges tab won't show up if you don't have one selected.  

How exactly did you come about the error?  

Also, be sure to clear your cache just to be safe.

Comment: Yes I have indeed cleared my cache and I have selected a database. I honestly do not know how to error came, I had not used Wamp in a long time, and when I came back to use it today, I found it didn't work

Comment: On your "General Settings" section...there seems to be a server-related error message? What does it say? My interpretation of the 'user'-file related error you are receiving is that you may have accidentaly deleted the file for the users table. But that can't be else I don't think phpmyadmin will even load... :\

Comment: I was thinking something similar - it is worthy to note that the "mysql" database (the actual database called "mysql") is completely empty according to PhpMyAdmin. Also, it was just saying "Server connection collation" in the general settings

Comment: Empty mysql DB? I've updated my answer with regards to this new bit of info.

Comment: @KevinPei I solved the same problem today, please check my answer :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you are sure that you are running as root, try clearing your cookies then refresh. This, AFAIK, is a bug affecting Google Chrome in particular but I can't say for certain for other browsers. Note that you can select what cookies to delete via the developers tab in Chrome. You need to delete only the localhost cookies.

Edit:

Oh no. So you've really deleted the 'user' table. My suggestion is that you either find CREATE scripts for the tables in database `mysql` or do a complete reinstall (as it appears, you don't have much DB's to lose anyway). Just for the record:

```
mysql> USE mysql;
Database changed
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+---------------------------+
| Tables_in_mysql           |
+---------------------------+
| columns_priv              |
| db                        |
| event                     |
| func                      |
| general_log               |
| help_category             |
| help_keyword              |
| help_relation             |
| help_topic                |
| host                      |
| ndb_binlog_index          |
| plugin                    |
| proc                      |
| procs_priv                |
| proxies_priv              |
| servers                   |
| slow_log                  |
| tables_priv               |
| time_zone                 |
| time_zone_leap_second     |
| time_zone_name            |
| time_zone_transition      |
| time_zone_transition_type |
| user                      |
+---------------------------+
24 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I've tried clearing cache, cookies, and sessions. I've also tried it in Chrome, IE, and Firefox. None of these worked

Answer (score 6):

For people who run into this problem while using cPanel / WHM the post linked to below on the cPanel site states:

> Per internal case number 37402, the functionality to add/delete/rename
>   users and databases through phpMyAdmin has been removed because of the
>   database mapping feature.

That means the Users / Privileges tab has been removed from cPanel's version of phpMyAdmin and it doesn't sound like it's coming back. The post is from December of 2013.

http://forums.cpanel.net/f354/phpmyadmin-users-tab-gone-367661.html

The cPanel staff member cPanelMichael who answered the post recommended two alternatives.

1. Use "Home > SQL Services > Database Map Tool."  This appears to be missing major functionality provided by phpMyAdmin.
2. Install your own standalone version of phpMyAdmin and use that
   instead of the cPanel version.

You gotta love progress.

Comment: For some version of cPanel use MySQL Database Wizard.

Comment: Working solution as of July 2021 on SQL version 5.7.33

Answer (score 2):

**I solved the problem like this:**

1) I set a root password through SQL query like this:

- On a main page you should see the current root user - usually `root@localhost`
- So query for password change:

   `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('YOURPASSWORDHERE');`

2) Search for `config.inc.php` in your wamp/xampp folder and change `auth_type`:

- you may find more of those configs, however the one you need is the one that contains line:
  `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'SOMETHING';` - change `'SOMETHING'` to `'cookie'`

  So you get: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';` (or http if you wish)
  -

3) clear/delete all browser cookies for your server (usually look for localhost or 127.0.0.1  cookies)

4) Go to phpyadmin's webpage again - now you will  be prompted with login box (html or http - depends on whether you set the cookie or http)

5) **LOGIN - AND YOU'RE DONE ! :)** Suddenly 'Privileges'/'Users' tab is shown, the exit button appears suddenly too ! :) (next to the "little house"-left-top)

PS: `config.inc.php` contains more interesting settings :)

Answer (score 2):

This one took me a long time to figure out as well as 'root' log in wasn't helping.

logged out and logged back in:

This time I put **root** as the username

And **use the same password as my user account and I was given access.**

This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Can you go into your `Users` tab at the top and edit your users (`root`, `admin`, `any`, whatever) by clicking on "Edit Privileges" and then under Administration, click `grant`?

Comment: The "users" tab simply does not exist for whatever reason - I've checked both the main page and the database pages

Comment: So, do you have any access on the databases at all? Can you say `CREATE USER 'username'@'servername' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.*
TO 'username'@'servername'
IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`  If you can't do these, then you have an access issue and should look into your configs.

Comment: When I attempt to do the following commands, I get the exact same error I mentioned in the question: "Can't find file: 'user' (errno: 2)"

Comment: Maybe try ResetMySQL: http://downloads.jlbn.net/ResetMysql.html  It seems likely that your config files are messed up.  Be sure to restart your services when you're trying all these things too.

Comment: Yowza, sorry I couldn't have been more help.  Upvoted for a chance that someone else can figure it out.  At this point, I'd be restarting my computer, reinstalling WAMP, and everything. :P

Answer (score 0):

You must be logging in as **"localhost"** @ **phpmyadmin page**

there are **limited privileges** given to the **"localhost"** user

**where as if you login in as "root" without any password
you'll have all the privilages and then you will see the user tab there on the phpmyadim homepage**

Answer (score 0):

Follow the root password change if you dont know the root password and then login in, it worked for me.

To change the mysql password for the root user, do the following:

1. unload `mysqld.nlm`
2. at the console, type: `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --autoclose`
3. at the server console type `mysql`

This will bring you to the mysql prompt.  At this prompt type the following: (Where ******** is the new password, NOTE: the single quotes ARE REQUIRED)

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('********') WHERE User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Flush privileges will make the change take effect immediately.

You can, in MySQL Version 3.22 and above, use the SET PASSWORD statement: (Where ******** is the new password, NOTE: the single quotes ARE REQUIRED)

```
shell> mysql -u root mysql
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR root=PASSWORD('********');
```

Another way to set the password is by using the mysqladmin command: (Where ******** is the new password)

```
shell> mysqladmin -u root password ********
shell> mysqladmin flush-privileges
```

Answer (score 0):

Truly, only one thing has worked for me. `root` with blank password didn't work even with AllowNoPassword option.
Notice that you could do *grant create* (instead of *grant all*) to grant only *create table* permissions. I want all permissions as it's for my local development.

---

My solution, it will give all you privileges there are for given user (make sure `phpmyadmin` is your username that you're able to log in with):

`sudo mysql`

`mysql> grant all on *.* to phpmyadmin@localhost;
 mysql> flush privileges;
 mysql> exit`

---

Then logout from PhpMyAdmin, log in again and you have all privileges.

Answer (score 0):

For me I've added this to the "config.inc.php" and it works well:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['DisableIS'] = true;
```