# No privileges on wamp server phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, privileges

I installed WAMP on Windows 8, and I'm having problems with MySQL privileges in phpMyAdmin.

Here, you can see the screenshot:

[image: phpMyAdmin screenshot]

As you can see, there is no privileges tab, and I can't a create new database.

Comment: In the phpMyAdmin folder on your disk, there is a `config.inc.php` file. Which user name is listed therein?

Comment: the username is root and the pass is empty

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';

thank you

Comment: You can use root for both username and password.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Phpmyadmin - Mysql no privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755214/phpmyadmin-mysql-no-privileges)

Comment: See my answer (works on Aug 2018)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699195/phpmyadmin-doesnt-show-privileges-tab/52114751#52114751

Answer (score 17):

Solution:

- Click on the *User accounts* tab
- Click on a user account showing no privileges
- Click on the *Edit privileges* link and tick all the check boxes

[image: phpMyAdmin]

Comment: I don't have a logout button. And I am logged in as root

Comment: use root as username and your password you set during phpmyadmin installation

Comment: Exactly what was needed!

Answer (score 4):

Go to phpmyadmin webpage under user accounts tab and check if the root has all_privileges

and still if you are not able create db

Go to mysql console login as root and type: flush privileges;

now reload phpmyadmin page and you should be in synch

Comment: did not helped.

Answer (score 3):

i just write UserName root and leave the password blank it work for me

Answer (score 2):

for no priviledge error, the solution is this:

It is not a file permission issue, the mysql user you logged in as doesn't have the right to create databases. You need to login as root for full permission, which I understand you are not. If I am not mistaken, the default password for "root" is empty (blank, nothing, ""), so try that. Once you are logged in as root in phpMyAdmin, you will be able to create databases or create another user with full permission.

kudos to:: http://www.theadminzone.com/forums/showthread.php?t=98676

Answer (score 1):

Hey i just tried this and it worked type the "root" as username and the password you set during installation.
Worked

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your authentication. If you are accessing phpMyAdmin through WAMP, then you need to check the files in WAMP for the proper configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to start the MySQL server with `--skip-grant-tables` option. Then access the *Users* tab in phpMyAdmin, and delete the password for `root@localhost` and `root@127.0.0.1`.

Comment: That works for the tables on the left side, but i steel cant see the privileges tab and i cant create database.

http://prntscr.com/1n64oa

http://prntscr.com/1n650c

Comment: Would you mind telling what the following SQL query result is? `select Host, User, Select_priv from mysql.user`

Comment: Ok, now on phpMyAdmin's home page, in the Database server section, do you see "User: root@localhost" ?

Comment: SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'user'

Answer (score -1):

you just ned to enter the username as 'root' and leave password blank.
You will be able to create database.