# No privileges in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, privileges

I know this question has been asked many times but none of the other solutions put in similar questions have worked.

I am trying to move my a WordPress site from one host to another. I have imported the wp database on to the new host and all I have to do is access the 'privileges' tab on phpmyadmin to make a user with all privileges. However, the privileges tab is not there. I have tried logging in as root but I get the message saying "Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)".

I have tried clearing my cookies and also adding a new user through the control panel making sure to tick the box saying "Give this user DBO access" but to no avail.

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue and make the privileges tab appear in phpmyadmin?

Thanks in advance,

James

Answer (score 3):

some hosting companies have a MySQL Databases user option ONLY on your cpanel.
[image: user part]

Comment: Thanks for the comment but unfortunately this section does not exist on the control panel the new host is using. I can add a user including username and password and I check the box saying "Give this user DBO access". Those are the only things appear on the add user screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try

**user:** Root

**pass:** Root

Sometimes this auto defaults, it sounds like you deleted your users data on accident.

Refer to: [Phpmyadmin doesn't show "privileges" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699195/phpmyadmin-doesnt-show-privileges-tab)
If your problems persist.

Comment: Unfortunately, root and root did not work. I have referred to that question already but no luck. I have spoken to the host and he has doesn't know why we are having this problem, we are both out of ideas.

Comment: Ask the host to check out his phpmyadmin.conf file.

Comment: Where is that located? I have access to the control panel and have the ftp details so can have a look at it myself

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your phpMyAdmin version, the "Privileges" tab has been renamed to "User accounts".

> "Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)".

If you really have no root password, on a database that's connected to the internet, you really should re-think this situation. As indicated in the error message, you should see the documentation section on [AllowNoPassword](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_AllowNoPassword) if you really wish to ignore my advice.

Comment: Hi Isaac Bennetch, that is the error I get when I type root and no password. At this point I'm willing to try anything. What would be your advice for finding a solution to this problem if not  going down the route of allowing no password?

Comment: Hi. To get phpMyAdmin to log in with a blank password, you need to add a line like `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;` to your `config.inc.php` configuration file. More information is available in the [phpMyAdmin manual](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_AllowNoPassword)

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestion. Unfortunately it did not work. I combined adding that code to config.inc.pho with flushing the cache but to no avail. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You still get the same error message about Login without a password is forbidden..."? If so, that suggests that perhaps you're not editing the right `config.inc.php` or that there's a problem with the way you've entered the setting. Try adding a line like `die("This is config.inc.php");` in `config.inc.php` and see if you get that message instead of the phpMyAdmin login page to confirm whether the configuration file is being loaded.

Comment: I'm getting the same comment. I'm uploading the config.inc.php file to the htdocs directory on the site. Is this correct? I included die("This is config.inc.php"); within a php tag and reset the cache. Still nothing. It appears my config.inc.php cannot be found

Comment: I'm experiencing this problem again on another site. The privileges tab is not available when I am using phpmyadmin on another host. Neither will let me log in as root.

Comment: `config.inc.php` should go in the main phpMyAdmin folder, not your site root. Most people would make a phpMyAdmin subdirectory under htdocs, so your configuration would go there instead of the site root. Hope that helps.